# what is the best cloud computing platform for a game server?

Tags: .net, azure, xna, cloud

I'm creating a multiplayer (non-browser) game with a friend. We already have a basic client and server - the game engine is implemented using XNA , c#, .NET, and the communication with the server (also written in c#) is done with lidgren. currently we only have a basic server logic, however we're planning to go big, and head for commercial use in the future.

That's why we thought we should use cloud computing, rather than having our own servers.
The first platform that came out to our minds is Azure. We heard that it requires a lot of learning, and vast modifications to the code, and therefore it should be integrated as early as possible. We are a bit worried of going in the wrong direction - as it is hard switching from one platform to another, once the whole logic fits one. Are there other alternatives to Azure? (I believe there are, otherwise I wouldn't have posted this question here...). What are the differences between them? Which one is more fitted to host game servers? which one is better documented, and in general, friendly to small start-up developers? (for instance, Azure gives first 3 month of usage for free). Do you have any other recommendations or remarks?

Thank you so much for reading the whole thing, and thanks even more for replying. :-)

Comment: To me, this is premature optimization. Firstly try to see if you actually need more than one server and then think about horizontal scaling. You can spend too much time thinking about something useless.

Comment: I can't answer your question, but one of the factors you should evaluate would be price as it relates to aggregate bandwidth usage.  Spend some time optimizing your client/server communication to minimize how much data you send back and forth to help minimize cost.

Comment: It's an interesting thought provoking question. I'm wondering if games-in-a-cloud have been ever done before? This seems like a no-brainer for indies, still I've never heard of such games.

Answer (score 1):

This is just my personal opinion but I think in terms of client/server deployment you should have a 3 part hierarchy. A master server handles all of the separate dedicated game-servers and each game-server hosts multiple clients. This would easily allow you to have a server browser.